# Apache get particular cookie value from response in httpd.conf

Tags: apache, logging, cookies, filter

I want to log a cookie value from response in Apache. How can I do that. The closest option is

```
Logformat "%{Set-Cookie}o"
```

this logs all cookies in response.

How can I extract a particular cookie value & log it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to log some RESTful service response information apache log file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038969/how-to-log-some-restful-service-response-information-apache-log-file)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `C` format string to log a cookie, such as this:

```
Logformat "%{Foobar}C"
```

to log the contents of cookie `Foobar`.

**References**

- [mod_log_config: Custom Log Formats, Format String](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats)

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, since it logs a cookie from the request, and the question was about getting it from the response.

Answer (score 1):

```
Logformat "%{Foobar}C"
```

This works with request only. If there is a new cookie being set in the response, this will **NOT** pick that up.